# Relative transmission delay to propagation delay

Tags: networking

I was given the following problem:

> Assume propagation delay is less than transmission delay on a link
>   connecting host A to B. If host A starts transmission at t=0, at
>   time equal to transmission delay, where is the first bit of the
>   packet?

With the solution being that the first bit has reached Host B.

However, I am having trouble understanding it.  If the transmission delay has elapsed, then wouldn't the packed have just been transmitted and therefore would be on the wire still?  Shouldn't the first bit reach Host B after the transmission delay + the propagation delay, regardless of how large they are in proportion to each other?  In other words, how could the packet transmit AND propagate in just the time it takes to transmit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right: Part of the **packet** might still be on the wire, but the **first bit** of the packet has already reached Host B.

- The transmission delay is the time interval from when Host A sends a packet to when the **last bit** of the packet leaves host A
- The propagation delay is the time interval from when **any** bit (including the first) of the packet leaves host A until **the same** bit arrives at host B

So since the propagation delay is less than the transmission delay the first bit has already arrived at host B.